# what would be a example in a general metric space about closedness and boundedness not imply sequential compactness?

Tags: metric-spaces

Unlike in $R^n$, closed and bounded doesn't guarantee sequential compactness. Textbook examples includes sup metric and R^infinite metric. I am wondering what would be a example of closed and bounded doesn't imply sequential compactness in more general Metric space $(X,\rho)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the space $l_2$ (ie, $d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_n |[x]_n - [y]_n|^2}$) and the set $C = \{ e_n \}_n$, where $e_n$ is the $n$th unit vector (ie, zeros everywhere except for the $n$th position which is one).

Then $C$ is bounded, closed but not compact (or sequentially compact).

Answer (score 1):

Take any metric space $(X,\rho)$ which is not sequentially compact (= compact, for metric spaces), and replace $\rho$ with the **standard bounded metric** $\rho_1(x,y) = \min(\rho(x,y),1))$.  Then $X$ itself is closed and $\rho_1$-bounded but not compact, despite the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275841/standard-bounded-metric-induces-same-topology) that the induced topology $\tau_{\rho_1}$ is the same as the induced topology $\tau_{\rho}$ of $(X,\rho)$.

I hope that this example drives home that the Heine-Borel Theorem is fundamentally a metric result and not a topological one.

Answer (score 0):

The closed unit ball in *any* infinite-dimensional normed space is not compact. This is an easy consequence of [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma).